# How to activate a bone after a certain threshold?

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to have a bone copy another bone's rotation after a certain point.

So, I have bone A copying the rotation of Bone B. But I only want Bone A to start copying when Bone B rotation reaches atleast 60º.

How can I create that function in Blender?

Comment: search for drivers. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using a driver to *enable* the copy-rotation of one bone based on the rotation parameter of another bone.

1. Add the copy rotation constraint to be desired bone
2. Create a new driver on *enabled* parameter of the constraint
3. edit the driver to be a scripted expression on a parameter (rotation) of the controlling bone.

[image]

Productivity hint: I actually went to the controlling bone W rotation param and RMB: "Copy as new driver" and then RMB Paste Driver into the enable.  This picked up the parameter reference variable.  I then edited the driver.

my example: [image]